# Can another object file being linked cause a segfault, even if it's not used in the code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a segfault that is only occurring when a certain object file is linked. The thing is, the class that's contained in this object file is not used in the `main()` function and the header isn't included either.

Is is possible that code within this other object file is causing a segfault?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You probably have undefined behavior in the  other files.

Comment: It might prove useful if you added the code which causes the segmentation fault when executed. Of course, it would require you to do some preliminary debugging first, in order to pin point exactly where the problem occurs. It might also improve the quality of this question, as is often measured by SO users (and might even revoke some of those down-votes).

Comment: This is not a specific programming problem; it's random speculation.

Comment: @zenith: Uh, yes, it is.

Answer (score 7):

There are all sorts of ways that including an additional object in a link can cause a program to malfunction.

A couple of common ones.

1. If the object file constructs a static object, simply including it
   in the link can cause additional code to be executed within the
   program.    There can be the direct problem of that object
   construction failing, with an exception being thrown.   There can
   also be indirect effects of changing the order of construction of
   other static objects - which is problematical if there is reliance
   on those objects being constructed in a specific order.
2. Linking an object file in means that all symbols in that object file become candidates for matching usage of those symbols in your program.  For example, let's say your code is using a function with C linkage named `foo()` from some library, and the additional object also contains a function named `foo()` which behaves differently than your program assumes.   Since symbols in object files (typically) are stronger matches than symbols in linked libraries, the version in the additional object file will probably be called instead.
3. Linking in another object can change layout of your program in memory.  If some part of your program exhibits undefined behaviour and trashes some area of memory, a consequence of linking in another object can be changing the effect of that undefined behaviour so making a previously invisible problem have a visible symptom (i.e. the memory being trashed is being used for something else, and the symptoms become detectable).

Comment: I might experience 3 at the moment. I have a compiled `*.so` library
that contains a buggy function that results in segmentation fault
when used, probably because of reading memory address it has not
previously allocated. I don't control this library so I can't peek
into its implementation. But when a big enough extra library is
*statically* linked thus increasing the binary size the problem goes
away and there is no segmentation fault when using a function from
`*.so` library.

Comment: It's not the binary size that matters, specifically - it is the layout of memory used by your program when running. Although there is a relationship, there isn't necessarily a one-to-one correspondence between the content of the executable (and any libraries) and how it uses memory when running.  Anyway ... what you're describing means either that your program, or the loaded library, (or both) has buggy code. Bear in mind that absence of a segfault doesn't mean the problem is gone - it just means the host system isn't detecting symptoms of a problem, not that the problem is not occurring

Comment: I think that including a library statically increases mostly `.text` size of the
binary. Writing to `.text` is `UB` but reading from `.text` is not I
think. That may be the reason why `segmentation fault` does not happen
- memory that a function in `*.so` tries to read is now a part of its
virtual memory. And you're correct that the problem is not solved but
rather swept under the rag - but there's nothing I can do about it
without the source code. I'm afraid that a potential upgrade to the
system such as changing `ld-linux.so` would break things.

Comment: You're misunderstanding.   Neither writing nor reading from `.text` represent undefined behaviour.   They are both potential consequences of code that exhibits undefined behaviour.   Reformatting your hard drive is as well.    Undefined behaviour does not mean "program crash".   It means "code doing something for which the C++ standard doesn't place any constraints on what is allowed to happen".

Comment: Anyway, all you have is evidence of a bug in either your program or the library.   If you have source code for neither, then you need to report the problem to the originators of both, and let them sort the problem out.   There are alternative techniques (e.g. stepping through with a debugger) it can be challenging enough to find flaws in your own code that way.   Easier to report to someone than try to find the cause and fix it yourself.

Comment: I know what `UB` is and I know that I'm lucky that I got segmentation
fault at some point at all because after the first occurrence of `UB`
further execution of the program is also undefined and one expect
everything. I think that in this case the reason of segmentation fault
is reading from a memory that has not been allocated. There is no
stack overflow - I used `valgrind` to increase stack size but the
problem still occurs.

I thought that `.text` is usually read-only so writing to it is `UB`
that *may* result in segmentation fault.